# Jekyll asset folder not created

Tags: jekyll

I am trying to learn how to use jekyll so i can create some sites and host them on github pages... But i am having a problem following the tutorial on the jekyll website, The css folder in the assets directory is not being created when i run jekyll build or jekyll serve, i have even tried bundle exec jekyll build and clean.

I have tried a few things still cant find a solution.

The github repo for my code is at https://github.com/blaze4dem/timiking please help me understand what i am doing wrong here.. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you're storing your scss in **_assets/css**, which as an underscored folder is ignored by jekyll.

Move it to **assets/css** folder, with no underscore. It will then be generated.

The second problem is how you call your generated css in _layouts/home.html.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/css/style.scss">
```

Requested from your index page at http://127.0.0.1:4000/timiking/, it resolve to http://127.0.0.1:4000/assets/css/style.scss then 404.

Simply use your `baseurl` :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/assets/css/style.css">
```

Comment: Thanks man... it worked but the style.scss does not change to style.css in the final build... any ideas on how to fix that? I mean the link in the html files does not change from scss to css

Comment: Read my answer until the end. In the `link` tag, we are targeting `{{ site.baseurl }}/assets/css/style.css` which is the result file for *assets/css/style.scss *.